# Custom Loop, Match Category with Page

Tags: loop

I want to set up my template so that Pages show a list of posts where the category slug matches the page slug. So on the Page "About Us" ('about'), posts tagged with the category-slug 'about'. The sidebar should show a list of these posts (I need to hardcode this. NO PLUGINS). Index.php should show all posts, EXcluding the posts that show up on a page.

This is the custom loop generates a list of recent posts that I will be adding to sidebar.php. This needs to be modified so that it only shows posts in a category that matches the page.

```
<ul>
<?php
query_posts( 'posts_per_page=5' );
if ( have_posts() ) :
      while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    ?><li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></li><?php
endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();
?>
</ul>
```

I tried to explain as clearly as possible, but it's a little confusing, so please me know what I need to make more clear.

Answer (score 1):

If this is going in a page.php (or similar) template, then using `query_posts()` is a bad idea and could have some pretty bad consequences. I also prefer [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) over `get_posts()` as it easily allows you to use template tags and it explicitly exists for running secondary loops on a page.

```
<?php
global $post;
$my_query_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5, // change this to any number or '0' for all
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $post->post_name // this gets the page slug
        )
    )
);
// a new instance of the WP_query class   
$my_query = new WP_Query( $my_query_args );

if( $my_query->have_posts() ) : while( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></li>

<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: How would you page this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your page slug is the same as the category slug? Anyway here is the code. It should be self explanatory.

```
<?php if(is_page()) : // check we are a page ?>
        <?php
        global $post;
        $cposts = get_posts("numberposts=5&category_name={$post->post_name}");
        if($cposts) : ?>
            <ul>
                <?php foreach($cposts as $cpost) : ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($cpost->ID) ?>"><?php echo $cpost->post_title; ?></a></li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me, quite simpel:

```
<h1><?php single_cat_title(); ?></h1>
```

Comment: Please explain how this solves the problem.