# Custom Loop, Match Category with Page: How to display post featured image?

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, get-posts

I found [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31064/custom-loop-match-category-with-page). It saved my day, but could you tell me how to display featured image of the post with the following code?

When I'm using

```
<?php echo $cpost->post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'alignleft')); ?>
```

An image does not show up...

Code below:

```
<?php if(is_page()) : // check we are a page ?>
    <?php global $post; $cposts = get_posts("numberposts=-1&category_name={$post->post_name}"); if($cposts) : ?>

            <?php foreach($cposts as $cpost) : ?>
             <div class="mb20"> 
                <h2><?php echo $cpost->post_title; ?></h2>
                <p><?php echo $cpost->post_content; ?></p>

                <?php echo $cpost->post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'alignleft')); ?>

            </div>  
            <?php endforeach; ?>


                <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Could you tell me how the correct code should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) fetches an array of [`WP_Post`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/post.php#L418) objects (see the [return values of `get_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post#Return) for a complete list of object properties).

In your above code snippet, you are iterating over said array with a `foreach` loop. Inside it, you are currently attempting to use a non-existent method ( `post_thumbnail()` ) of those objects.

Instead, make use of the [`get_the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) function and feed it the current post objects' ID property as a first argument:

```
<?php
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $cpost->ID, 'thumbnail', array( 'class' => 'alignleft' ) );
?>
```

That answers the core of your question.
As an aside, let me point out that you do not need `<?php` opening and closing tags on every line. So here's a complete revision of your snippet:

```
<?php
    if ( is_page() ) {

        global $post;

        $cposts = get_posts( array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'category_name' => $post->post_name
        ));

        if ( $cposts ) {
            foreach ( $cposts as $cpost ) {

                echo '<div class="mb20">' .
                        '<h2>' . $cpost->post_title . '</h2>' .
                        '<p>' . $cpost->post_content . '</p>' .
                        get_the_post_thumbnail(
                            $cpost->ID,
                            'thumbnail',
                            array( 'class' => 'alignleft' )
                        ) .
                    '</div>';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```